# Get a `&mut u8` reference to part of a `&mut u32`

Tags: rust

To convert a `u32` to its bytes, I know there is already:

- [`u32::to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_le_bytes)
- [`u32::to_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_be_bytes)
- [`u32::to_ne_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_ne_bytes)
- [`u32::from_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_le_bytes)
- [`u32::from_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be_bytes)
- [`u32::from_ne_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_ne_bytes)

However, is there any sound and cross-platform way to convert a `&mut u32` into references of its bytes, as `&mut u8`?

Like this:

```rust
fn as_be_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32) -> [&mut u8; 4] {
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    let mut num: u32 = 0x12345678;

    // Prints `0x12345678 - [12, 34, 56, 78]`
    println!("{:#x} - {:x?}", num, num.to_be_bytes());

    let parts = as_be_bytes_mut(&mut num);
    *parts[2] = 0xfe;

    // Should print `0x1234fe78 - [12, 34, fe, 78]`
    println!("{:#x} - {:x?}", num, num.to_be_bytes());
}
```

The rationale is that it should be theoretically possible, because there are no invalid states of a `u32`, no matter how you modify its underlying bytes.

---

Attempt:

```rust
fn as_ne_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32) -> [&mut u8; 4] {
    unsafe {
        let ptr: *mut u8 = (num as *mut u32).cast();
        [
            &mut *ptr.add(0),
            &mut *ptr.add(1),
            &mut *ptr.add(2),
            &mut *ptr.add(3),
        ]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut num: u32 = 0x12345678;

    println!("{:#x} - {:x?}", num, num.to_be_bytes());

    let parts = as_ne_bytes_mut(&mut num);
    *parts[1] = 0xfe;

    println!("{:#x} - {:x?}", num, num.to_be_bytes());
}
```

```
0x12345678 - [12, 34, 56, 78]
0x1234fe78 - [12, 34, fe, 78]
```

I think (tm) this is sound, because a `u32` is a packed array of `u8`'s and `u8`'s are always correctly aligned, and the lifetimes should also match. I didn't find a way yet to implement as_be/le_bytes_mut yet. Also I'm not 100% sure this is sound, so some feedback would help.

Comment: So bit shifting is not enough?

Comment: @JakubDóka You can't get a mutable reference through bitshifting.

Comment: No, but you can do what you shown in your example with bit manipulation

Comment: @JakubDóka Well yes of course, but I want to get a mutable reference, to expose just part of the `u32` through an API.

Comment: @JakubDóka The usecase is that I want to use DMA in embedded, and it forces me to layout my data in `[u32]`. My data consists of multiple single bytes, packed in a `u32`. I of course could implement setter/getter that set/get parts of those `u32`, but I wondered if it would be possible to expose `&mut` references to the parts directly.

Comment: I think you can check what endianess the platform has trough attributes if that helps

Comment: @JakubDóka Which attributes? Would you mind a link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#target_endian)

Comment: I think you can just transmute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *should* be sound to get a `&mut [u8; 4]` out of it.

```rs
pub fn as_ne_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32) -> &mut [u8; 4] {
    unsafe {
        let arr: *mut [u8; 4] = (num as *mut u32).cast();
        &mut *arr
    }
}
```

This is much better than `[&mut u8; 4]` since it's a no-op. However, you aren't going to be able to create `le` and `be` versions unless you swap the bits around and return an `impl DerefMut<Target = &mut [u8; 4]>` guard that swaps the bits back when it's dropped.

I would probably go with four functions that return one byte each instead of `le` and `be` functions that return `[&mut u8; 4]`. Although if you use them the same, they should optimize to the same thing.

```rs
pub fn most_sig_byte_0(num: &mut u32) -> &mut u8 {
    if cfg!(target_endian = "big") {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[0]
    } else {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[3]
    }
}

pub fn most_sig_byte_1(num: &mut u32) -> &mut u8 {
    if cfg!(target_endian = "big") {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[1]
    } else {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[2]
    }
}

pub fn most_sig_byte_2(num: &mut u32) -> &mut u8 {
    if cfg!(target_endian = "big") {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[2]
    } else {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[1]
    }
}

pub fn most_sig_byte_3(num: &mut u32) -> &mut u8 {
    if cfg!(target_endian = "big") {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[3]
    } else {
        &mut as_ne_bytes_mut(num)[0]
    }
}
```

Miri thinks these are fine, at least. You could make them a single const generic function, but it would be less ergonomic to give it the `0..4` bound. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=35158fde09016e23b8eaa064bfd209c7)

Comment: You can use `bytemuck` to do it safely: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=efff82fbec070a0bd88f127b37e42c6c.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the help of `cfg(target_endian = "...")`:

```rust
pub fn as_ne_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32) -> [&mut u8; 4] {
    unsafe {
        let ptr: *mut u8 = (num as *mut u32).cast();
        [
            &mut *ptr.add(0),
            &mut *ptr.add(1),
            &mut *ptr.add(2),
            &mut *ptr.add(3),
        ]
    }
}

pub fn as_be_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32) -> [&mut u8; 4] {
    let mut b = as_ne_bytes_mut(num);

    #[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
    b.reverse();

    b
}

pub fn as_le_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32) -> [&mut u8; 4] {
    let mut b = as_be_bytes_mut(num);
    b.reverse();
    b
}

fn main() {
    let mut num: u32 = 0x12345678;

    // Prints `0x12345678 - [12, 34, 56, 78]`
    println!("{:#x} - {:x?}", num, num.to_be_bytes());

    let parts = as_be_bytes_mut(&mut num);
    *parts[2] = 0xfe;

    // Should print `0x1234fe78 - [12, 34, fe, 78]`
    println!("{:#x} - {:x?}", num, num.to_be_bytes());
}
```

```
0x12345678 - [12, 34, 56, 78]
0x1234fe78 - [12, 34, fe, 78]
```

While it does look a little convoluted, the compiler manages to [optimize it perfectly](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/fsaEcbaqc):

```
example::as_ne_bytes_mut:
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rcx, [rsi + 1]
        lea     rdx, [rsi + 2]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rsi
        add     rsi, 3
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rcx
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rdx
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 24], rsi
        ret

example::as_be_bytes_mut:
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rcx, [rsi + 1]
        lea     rdx, [rsi + 2]
        lea     rdi, [rsi + 3]
        mov     qword ptr [rax], rdi
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 24], rsi
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 8], rdx
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 16], rcx
        ret

example::as_le_bytes_mut:
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rcx, [rsi + 1]
        lea     rdx, [rsi + 2]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], rsi
        add     rsi, 3
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 24], rsi
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 8], rcx
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rdx
        ret
```

Comment: This should be sound, you can also add a test if byte order matches the std functions

Comment: Also, you can check the soundness trough miri, it gives bit more confidence

Comment: Your `as_le_bytes` always reverses. You need a `#[cfg(target_endian = "big")]`

Comment: @drewtato Yes, it does. It always reverses from `as_be_bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this without pointer arithmetics.

Code:

```rust
pub fn as_le_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32)->[&mut u8; 4]{
    let num_slice = std::slice::from_mut(num);
    let (pref, middle, suff): (_,&mut [u8],_) = unsafe{
        num_slice.align_to_mut()
    };
    // This would be always true when we cast to u8
    assert!(pref.is_empty() && suff.is_empty());
    
    match middle {
        #[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
        [a, b, c, d] => [a, b, c, d],
        #[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
        [a, b, c, d] => [d, c, b, a],
        _ => unreachable!()
    }
}

pub fn as_be_bytes_mut(num: &mut u32)->[&mut u8; 4]{
    let mut r = as_le_bytes_mut(num);
    r.reverse();
    r
}
```

And it compiles to nice assembly too: [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:22,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:22,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27pub+fn+as_le_bytes_mut(num:+%26mut+u32)-%3E%5B%26mut+u8%3B+4%5D%7B%0A++++let+num_slice+%3D+std::slice::from_mut(num)%3B%0A++++let+(pref,+middle,+suff):+(_,%26mut+%5Bu8%5D,_)+%3D+unsafe%7B%0A++++++++num_slice.align_to_mut()%0A++++%7D%3B%0A++++//+This+would+be+always+true+when+we+cast+to+u8%0A++++assert!!(pref.is_empty()+%26%26+suff.is_empty())%3B%0A++++%0A++++match+middle+%7B%0A++++++++%23%5Bcfg(target_endian+%3D+%22little%22)%5D%0A++++++++%5Ba,+b,+c,+d%5D+%3D%3E+%5Ba,+b,+c,+d%5D,%0A++++++++%23%5Bcfg(target_endian+%3D+%22big%22)%5D%0A++++++++%5Ba,+b,+c,+d%5D+%3D%3E+%5Bd,+c,+b,+a%5D,%0A++++++++_+%3D%3E+unreachable!!()%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+as_be_bytes_mut(num:+%26mut+u32)-%3E%5B%26mut+u8%3B+4%5D%7B%0A++++let+mut+r+%3D+as_le_bytes_mut(num)%3B%0A++++r.reverse()%3B%0A++++r%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1690,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-O%27,overrides:!((name:edition,value:%272021%27)),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.69.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: This is pretty sweet. Never heard of `align_to_mut` before. Interesting. Also, I find it interesting that Rust removes asserts it can prove to be true at compile time.

Comment: Asserts are removed by Dead Code Elimination optimization. It is fairly common optimization in many languages.